# Enable microphone on boot

Tags: gnome3, alsa, pulseaudio

On Arch Linux with Gnome 3.14, the microphone is disabled by default. So every time I need to use Skype I need to open Sound settings and enable the mic.

How do I enable the mic so that it's available for Skype, etc when necessary?

Comment: have you taken a look here? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/skype#Access_Pulseaudio_controls_when_using_Skype_as_a_different_user Also are you saving you alsa configuration ?

Comment: How do you save alsa configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to this issue.

I simple installed the `pavucontrol` package. Once I rebooted, the microphone was enabled by default.